# Proof of property of scalar functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^1$ which satisfies, for a given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$$x \cdot \nabla f(x) = \alpha f(x) $$

Prove that $f$ satisfies $f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$.

Proving the converse is trivial. You differentiate $f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$, develop the equation a little bit, set $t=1$ and you get the result.

Proving the forward result has proved to be more challenging. I have already thought of applying Lagrange's mean value theorem, but I wasn't able to do so.

I would say that the beginning of the proof also starts by differentiating $\ f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$. However I am not seeing where to go from there. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x \cdot \nabla f(x) = \alpha f(x)$ for all $x$. If $\alpha = 0$ then $\nabla f(x)$ is identically zero so that $f$ is constant and trivially satifies $f(tx) = f(x)$. We will thus assume $\alpha \not= 0$.

Suppose $\alpha > 0$. Fix a point $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and define $\phi(t) = f(tx) - t^\alpha f(x)$ for $t \in \mathbb R$. Note that $\phi(1) = 0$. The chain rule gives you $$\phi'(t) = x \cdot \nabla f(tx) - \alpha t^{\alpha - 1} f(x)$$ so under the stated hypothesis you have $$t \phi'(t) = (tx) \cdot \nabla f(tx) - \alpha t^\alpha f(x) = \alpha f(tx) - \alpha t^\alpha f(x) = \alpha \phi(t)$$ for all $t$. The solutions to this equation all have the form $\phi(t) = Ct^\alpha$, and since $\phi(1) = 0$ we must have $\phi(t) = 0$. It follows that $f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

If $\alpha < 0$ you can argue as in the paragraph above to find that $f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$ provided that $t > 0$. Unfortunately as $t \to 0^+$ you end up with $|f(0)| = \infty$ unless $f(x) = 0$. For this condition to hold for all $x$ requires that $f$ is identically zero, and $f(tx) = t^\alpha f(x)$ holds trivially.